# Adding background color to title slide in beamer

Tags: beamer, backgrounds

How can I add a solid background color only to the title slide in `beamer`?

This is what I am doing after `\begin{document}`

```
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue}
\begin{frame}
Hello
\end{frame}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can temporarily change colors between frames.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\author{Beamer Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage  
\end{frame}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
\frame{The remaining frames $M=at^h$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer and I have tried every possible way of making it work even before posting the question, but for some reason it does not work for me, the background color is not set. Is there some way of troubleshooting this?

Comment: @user10211 If you can edit your question an include a very basic and minimal example we might look at it together.

Comment: I just edited my question to include the example.

Comment: @user10211: How is your edited post any different from @ percusse's answer? We would still not know why your approach does not work because of that. Provide [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that clearly shows your problem and include any errors or warnings you receive. It could be that you have an out-of-date distribution, or perhaps that you use packages that conflict with solution.

Comment: SOLVED: It was my bad. In the documentclass declaration, I had an option "ignorenonframetext". This was the root cause of all the problems.:)