# Adding background color to specific slide in beamer when using rmarkdown

Tags: beamer, color, knitr, markdown

I want to highlight an entire slide in a presentation I am creating in R markdown, much in the same way as was done in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39074/14826) (without using markdown).

Cannot seem to figure it out though. Below is a dummy example of my failure so far...

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: beamer_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

% \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}

## Slide with R Output 

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}

```{r cars, echo = TRUE}
summary(cars)
```
````

Comment: Does `colortheme: "dolphin"` work? (Reference: [this website](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/beamer_presentation_format.html#themes).)

Comment: @heather only to change the whole set of slides, not a specific slide

Comment: Okay, sorry, I'll keep looking.

Comment: throws a pandoc error.

Comment: yeah, I made a mistake with that last one, that's why I deleted it (that was normal LaTeX, not R markdown...sorry). I'm still looking

Comment: First of all I have to say that I have absolutely no idea about this whole markdown business. But I seems that your biggest problem is that changing the background colour has to happen after one slide is finished but before the new one starts. Maybe the `afterpage` package could help with that?

Comment: @gjabel Offtopic: I saw your deleted answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129171/36296 and I really think it answers the question and it's quality is on the same level as the other answers to this question. Can you please think about un-deleting it? I can't understand why it was flagged as not an answer, as it does work.

Answer (score 3):

I created a key, `bgcolor`, that can be passed as an option to a frame.  In the example below, only the second slide has a red background.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{bgcolor}[]{%
  \ifx#1\@empty\else
    \def\ps@navigation@colored{%
      \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=#1}%  background color
      \@nameuse{ps@navigation}}
    \thispagestyle{navigation@colored}
  \fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Test
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[bgcolor=red]
  Test
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
  Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could hardcode for which frame number the background colour should be changed. This can be done in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
    \if\insertframenumber2
        \color{red}\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```